# Can't install @types packages: Host key verification failed

Tags: node.js, git, typescript, npm

When I try to run the following command:

```
npm install @types/react
```

I get the following output:

```
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react Cloning into bare repository
'C:\Users\lifeg\AppDa
    ta\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-types-react-e0f5ee6a'...
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react Host key verification failed.
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react Please make sure you have the correct access right
    s
    npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/react and the repository exists.
    npm ERR! addLocal Could not install types/react
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\lifeg\Documents\GitRepositorie
    s\Personal\ReactMarkdown\types\react'
    npm ERR!     at Error (native)
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
"C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\npm\\t
    ools\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@types/react"
    npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\lifeg\Documents\GitRepositories\Personal\ReactMarkdown
    npm ERR! node -v v6.8.1
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\lifeg\Documents\GitRepositories\Personal\ReactMarkdown\types\react
    npm ERR! syscall stat
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\lifeg\Documents\GitRepositories\Personal\ReactMarkdown\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Note the versions of Node/NPM:

```
npm ERR! node -v v6.8.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
```

Something about the output suggests that the package was not installed correctly.

I get similar results when I try to install other `@types` packages, but packages like `react` install properly.

I updated NPM and the same error occurred before and after the update (the output is after).

Performing `npm cache clean` did nothing.

The error seems to be related to git and SSH, even though `install` is supposed to try accessing git through HTTPS first, it doesn't seem to want to do that in this case.

### The problem

Basically, at one time I had experimented with a Windows package manager called [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and used it to install node.

However, I later re-installed node and NPM using the official installer. The two installations existed side-by-side and caused a variety of strange side-effects.

One of them was that when I ran `npm install -g npm` and it would update the version of NPM that came with node using the version that came with chocolatey. This caused me to have an outdated version of NPM, which [which is problematic when working with Git](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7253)

Comment: Check what's your `npm` version and try removing npm cache

Comment: @Martin I added the NPM version. I also cleaned the NPM cache, but it did not help.

Comment: You have really old `npm`. I don't even think that's the `npm` that comes with your `node`. I have `node` v6.9.1 and `npm` 3.10.8.

Comment: @Martin Yikes. You're right. I didn't notice. I'm pretty sure I know what causes it. I think I have two versions of NPM on my system.

Comment: Yea, I thought it's going to be something like this :)

Comment: @Martin if you post an answer I'll approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `npm` is very old and it's probably not the one that comes with your `node` package.